# How to automatically generate multiple RMD files using a list of parameters in Excel?

Tags: r, shiny, automation, r-markdown

I hope you are well, I tell you my problem. I have a dashboard in .RMD format that works with Shiny and Flexdashboard and when I change a parameter inside the dashboard a completely new one is generated.

What I want to do is to automatically generate 300 dashboards with some identifiers that I have in Excel, which would be the parameters of the .RMD file.

Does anyone have an approximation of how to solve this?

I leave an image, what is enclosed in red circles are the parameters to be changed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add placeholders for these "identifiers" as `params` in your YAML header, then read them from Excel into R and then cycle through them, passing them to your `.Rmd` using the `params` argument in `rmarkdown::render()` and `purr::map()`.

So to your YAML you would add:

```
---
params:
  identifier: "identifier1"
---
```

and then you could write a render function like this

```
render_func <- function(x){
  rmarkdown::render("mymarkdown.Rmd", params = list(x))
}
```

and pass the vector of "identifiers" you read in from excel which might resemble this:

`params_list <- c("identifier1", "identifier2", "identifier3")`

and then call your render function for each "identifier" or "param" in your list read in from Excel:

`purrr::map(params_list, render_func)`